# Direct 2D HLSL pixel shader coordinate space

Tags: hlsl, direct2d

In the custom effect [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/custom-effects) it says to calculate relative offsets for pixels using this formula :

```
float2 sampleLocation =
        texelSpaceInput0.xy    // Sample position for the current output pixel.
        + float2(0,-10)        // An offset from which to sample the input, specified in pixels.
        * texelSpaceInput0.zw; // Multi
```

For my video sequencer I have included custom effects and transitions many of them converted to HLSL from Glsl from ShaderToy. The code in Glsl uses normalized coordinates [0...1] and many calculations rely on absolute xy position, rather than relative, so I have to find a way to use absolute texture coordinates in my HLSL code.

So, that zw multiplicator I use to find the UV of the bottom right sample :

```
float2 FindLast(float2 MV)
{
    float2 LastSample = float2(0, 0) + float2(WI,he)* MV;
    return LastSample;
}
```

The width and height are passed to the effect as a constant buffer.

After that, the normalized coordinates are :

```
float2 GetNormalized(float2 UV,float2 MV)
{
    float2 s = FindLast(MV);
    return UV / s;
}
```

This works. Code from shader toy that would apply in normalized coordinate works fine in my effects. D2DSampleInput with that uv input returns the correct color.

The question is whether my solution is viable. For example I have assumed that the first top left pixel is at uv 0,0, is that correct and viable?

I'm new in HLSL and shaders, so I would appreciate your help.

Comment: This is correct, but the doc is not fully up to date. For Direct2D, you're supposed to use d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli (from Windows SDK) that brings some macros that hide these details. You can see that in samples: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/D2DCustomEffects/cpp/PixelShader/RippleEffect.hlsl and hlsl files in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/D2DAdvancedColorImages/cpp/D2DAdvancedColorImages

Comment: I use the macros but I can't seem to find a macro that can get a pixel in a specific normalized location. These samples do not take arbitrary texture pictures.

Comment: All macros are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/hlsl-helpers like D2DGetInput, D2DSampleInput this is all you get. Direct2D effects kinda restricts what you can do with DirectX shaders.